# Can not build PHP 8.2.x with mcrypt 1.0.6 on Windows 10

Tags: mcrypt, php-8.2

I compiled PHP 8.2.11 on Windows 10 but I got stuck with mcrypt 1.0.6. There is no pre-compiled dll from pecl.php.net.

I have tried to install with pecl as below

```
> pecl install mcrypt-1.0.6
```

It shows the error No releases available for package

```
pecl.php.net/mcrypt
```

I have updated pecl channel, etc. but the error is still there. I trying to search how to compile mcrypt with php 8.2 or compile mcrypt separately. However, there is not much information to compile in Windows.

I tried to compile php and put mcrypt in ext folder but it shows configure: error: mcrypt.h not found during the process. The compiling process is successful but there is no mcrypt because of the error.

Please help because there is a requirement to upgrade our web app to php.8.2 but got stuck with mcrypt

Thank you very much!